# Algorithm to get all Possible Combinations

Tags: php, algorithm

I have four slots. Each slot can either be a 0 or a 1. How would I make the loop to get all possible combinations? How do I even approach the problem?

**Here's the context:**

In the database table, there are four fields (view, create, edit, delete). Each field can either be a 0 or a 1. I'm looking to save every possible combination.

Comment: The answer is 16 because it is 2^4. Or do you mean make it display each combination?

Comment: Count up from 0 to 15 in binary. Each number will correspond to a combination.

Comment: I just didn't know what to do with the loop when counting to 15 in binary. Yes I meant to display the results and then insert each combination into the database table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could approach it with 4 nested loops:

```
for ($a=0; $a<=1; $a++) {
    for ($b=0; $b<=1; $b++) {
        for ($c=0; $c<=1; $c++) {
            for ($d=0; $d<=1; $d++) {
                echo "$a $b $c $d\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This yields:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
...
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

Or, you could just extract binary digits from numbers in [0, 16) range:

```
for ($i=0; $i<16; $i++) {
    $a = ($i & 8) ? 1 : 0;
    $b = ($i & 4) ? 1 : 0;
    $c = ($i & 2) ? 1 : 0;
    $d = ($i & 1) ? 1 : 0;
    echo "$a $b $c $d\n";
}
```